# how to insert a line feed into a sed line concatenation

Tags: awk, sed, concatenation

I have this code fragment:

```
cat testfeed.txt | sed '${H;z;x;s/\n//g;p;};/0$/!{H;d;};/0$/{H;z;x;s/\r//g;}'
```

which takes all my input and creates one long record.
What I want is to concatenate record one with records two

so that:

```
1.

My first line

2.

My Second line
```

becomes:

```
1. My First line

2. My Second line
```

Instead of:

```
1. My First line. 2. My Second line
```

I feel I should be able to insert a line feed but my knowledge of sed is poor at best :(

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want the _first 2_ lines to be left on their own lines, but all remaining ones to be joined with a space each, so that you end up with _3_ lines in total?

Comment: It would be good to mark the answer accepted (or) upvote the answer, assuming your problem is _solved_ now. Also once you accept it, it can be made useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat testfeed.txt 
1.

My first line

2.

My Second line
```

with `GNU sed`

```
$ sed 'N;N; s/\n\s*\n/ /; N' testfeed.txt 
1. My first line

2. My Second line
```

- `N;N;` get two more lines, so total three lines
- `s/\n\s*\n/ /` from those three lines, replace first occurence of `\n\s*\n` with a space... for example, this would match end of the line containing `1.` and the empty line that follows (which can contain `\s` characters, can be removed if line doesn't have `\s` characters)
- the last `; N` will get one more line, so that next match will start from line containing `2.`